# Копипаст из файла .xlsx в Google sheets

Tags: python, excel, google-spreadsheet, openpyxl, google-sheets-api

Есть ли возможность с помощью `python` скопировать содержимое файла Excel, заполненного с помощью `openpyxl`, в таблицу Google Sheets?

Знаю о Google Sheets API, но не знаю о возможности вставить скопированное содержимое из Excel файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете импортировать данные CSV с помощью метода [`gspread.Client.import_csv`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.import_csv).

Краткий пример из документации:

```
import gspread

# Check how to get `credentials`:
# https://github.com/burnash/gspread

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# Read CSV file contents
content = open('file_to_import.csv', 'r').read()

gc.import_csv('<SPREADSHEET_ID>', content)
```

Это загрузит ваш CSV-файл на первый лист электронной таблицы [`<SPREADSHEET_ID>`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id).

**Внимание**

Этот метод удаляет все остальные листы, а затем полностью заменяет содержимое первого листа.